# Python async call to regular function

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, automation, python-asyncio

I am trying to run async function that will call to a regular function.

Tried this:

```
import asyncio
from okta.client import Client as OktaClient


def startFunc(metadataURL,appID):
  print("This is the",metadataURL, appID)


config = {
'orgUrl': 'https://example.com',
'token': 'myToken'}

okta_client = OktaClient(config)
async def skipFunc():
 apps, resp, err = await okta_client.list_applications()

 for app in apps:
   appsList = (app.label,app.id)
   for app.label in appsList:
     if app.label == 'John':
       strApp = str(app)
       appJson = ast.literal_eval(strApp)
       metadataURL = (appJson['links']['metadata']['href'])
       appID = (appJson['id'])
       startFunc(metadataURL,appID) ## Trying to call this function

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(skipFunc())
```

I do not receive the output, It looks like the function startFunc() didn't execute and I am not getting any error.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: It also looks like `startFunc()` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Hi, It's updated now.

Comment: Are you sure that `app.label` is ever `"John"`?

Comment: Yes, if I print `strApp` I receive the output of the app named `"John"`, I also can print the other variables `appID` and `metadataURL` which part of the output of `strApp`.

Comment: `strApp` and `app.label` are not the same thing in the code you've shared, so please double-check that the condition is really met.

Comment: Also, any reason why you are not using [`asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run)?